# Laravel 8 Problem Foreign key in two table error

Tags: mysql, laravel-8, php-8

After creating the user table schema and the user_type table schema it constantly gives me problems with the foreign key I set the db in utf8 if it can be a problem, I've been hitting my head for hours but I can't get out of it.

```
Schema::create('users_panel', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table
            ->id();
        $table
            ->unsignedBigInteger('id_type_user');
        $table
            ->string('company_name');
        $table
            ->string('email')->unique();
        $table
            ->string('password', 60);
        $table
            ->timestamp('email_verified_at')
            ->nullable();
        $table
            ->string('representative_name')
            ->nullable();
        $table
            ->string('phone_number')
            ->nullable();
        $table
            ->string('address');
        $table
            ->rememberToken();
        $table
            ->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('users_panel', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table
            ->foreign('id_type_user')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('type_users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

type_users:

```
Schema::create('type_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('type_user');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

error:
PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `prysma_db`.`users_panel` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")

Answer (score 1):

You should follow this:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#renaming-tables-with-foreign-keys

I think this you have mixed up something else here. It would be better if you could share the error with line.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/fXxWX7wb